# I want to append my data below the table and search when user clicks in the product id field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. I have created a table and I want to add the data below the table but data is being added at the top,
2. I have written a search property when user enters the product `id` the data should be shown and can't figure out where my code went wrong,
3. I want to add serch field to all the buttons should I write the code many times is there any solution?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var url = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/getAllData";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //console.log("AllData")
    var obj = data['AllData'];
    //console.log(obj)
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + obj[i]["ProductID"] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + obj[i]["Title"] + "</td>" +


        $("#mytable").append('<tr class="child"> tr</tr>');
    }
  });
});

function goodCall() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    });
  });



}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("banner.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

#mytable {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

#mytable td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#mytable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#mytable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div style="margin-left:25%">

  <h1 style="color:white;">TITLE DETAILS</h1>

  <div class="w3-container" id="add">
    <div class="" style="color:white;">
      <form name="test_form" id="101">
        <table class="table borderless">
          <tr>
            <th>Title Identifier</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="border:none">
              <b>PRODUCT ID</b>

              <br>
              <input type="text" id="id" style="color:black;" required></td>
            <td style="border:none"></td>
            <td style="border:none">
              <b>PRODUCT TITLE</b>

              <br><input type="text" id="title" style="color:black;" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td style="border:none">
              <br> <b>director </b>
              <br> <input type="text" id="ter" style="color:black;" required>
            </td>
            <td style="border:none"></td>
            <td style="border:none">
              <b>producer</b>
              <br> <input type="text" id="media" style="color:black;" required>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </form>
      <input type="button" onclick="goodCall()" value="Search" style="color:Red;">
      <table id='mytable'>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>PRODUCTTITLE</th>

        </tr>
        <div>
          <br><br>
        </div>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Error in the code - <table id='mytable'> added two times in HTML

Comment: should this `$("#mytable").append('<tr class="child"> tr</tr>');` be like `$("#mytable").append('<tr class="child">' + tr +'</tr>');` ???

Comment: can anyone explain why whole body is erased when image is removed i mean headings to text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a basic functional example https://jsfiddle.net/0Lvqcd8t/39/

You should change this:

```
var tr = "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + obj[i]["ProductID"] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + obj[i]["Title"] + "</td>" +


        $("#mytable").append('<tr class="child"> tr</tr>');
```

for this:

```
var tr = "<td>" + obj[i]["ProductID"] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + obj[i]["Title"] + "</td>" +


        $("#mytable").append('<tr class="child">'+ tr+'</tr>');
```

In the first case you are creating `<tr><tr class="child><td></td></tr>` (first `<tr>` is wrong) and browser will render something like `<tr>tr</tr><tr class='child'>empty</tr>` also, `tr` var in first example is not interpreted as variable, so you should place it like `+tr+`. I've made a basic filter function at the end that works with id.

Comment: Thanks for the help
what if i want to  use the search function to every text field should (i am having 13 text fields should i write 13 times ) plese any suggestion